# Mount a FTP(S) Server to a linux directory

Tags: linux, ftp, fuse

I know i can mount over ssh/sftp/sshfs using FUSE, but can the same work with FTP/FTPS?

the aim is to mount a FTPS server to e.g. /databackup

I cant use SSH/SFTP/SSHFS as the host of the other server does not support those methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [curlftpfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/). See the examples in the page.

Comment: Unfortunately, `curlftpfs` does not mount files and folders with the right time stamp. They are randomly shifted between 0 and 24 hours, which for synchronizing is a sheer disaster. In addition, visiting file trees in curlftpfs can be slower than other mounting methods, such as simply using the file manager, e.g., *Nautilus*

Answer (score 1):

I have always liked using [lftp](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/lftp1.html) with the mirror option.  It sounds like it might work pretty good for you based on the /databackup example.  There is a brief example given [here](http://techgage.com/print/backing_up_your_linux) under the section called **Backup To Remote Server, rsync Without Passwords.**  (Regardless of the heading it does talk about lftp usage)